# Selenium python on instagram

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

I'm trying to do some web-scraping on instagram with selenium. specifically i'm trying to log-in by this address
https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/
with selenium.

On this page, the input 'username' is written like this

```
<input class="_ph6vk _o716c" aria-describedby="" aria-label="Phone number, username, or email" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="30" name="username" placeholder="Phone number, username, or email" value="" type="text">
```

What i'm doing in python is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


driver=webdriver.Firefox() 
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')

input_username = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
input_username.send_keys("username")
```

Python returns me : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

So I did the same changing this:

```
input_username[0].send_keys("username")
```

And the error is:

IndexError: list index out of range

So, the array is empty. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Personally I'd use a higher level library like [Splinter](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for this - using Selenium for this is a pain. That said, scraping is probably the wrong approach. Instagram has a decent API and you should probably be using that rather than scraping the site.

Comment: have you tried directly searching by find_element_by_name?

Comment: @MatthewDaly i want to create an instagram account with python, API doesn't support creating accounts, that's why i'm trying to do it with selenium. I'll try splinter

Comment: @NimishBansal Yes, I already did. This error return me. 
Message: Unable to locate element: [name="username"]

Comment: it worked perfectly fine on my system

Comment: @NimishBansal With my code? Really?

Comment: yes with your code. :)

Comment: @NimishBansal How's that possible?

Comment: amm if your net is a little slow add time.sleep(some_int).

Comment: Let the form load on the page, you can always check load events in selenium, whether it is page or any other element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
time.sleep(2)
user_name=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[1]/div/input')
user_name.send_keys('user_name')
password=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div/input')
password.send_keys('pa$$')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/span[1]/button').click()
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It's working now. Probably it was the "time.sleep(2)". I dont know, but really thanks!

Comment: using `time.sleep(2)` might work, but you can never be sure about the time it will take to load.

Comment: @bhansa i just gave him hint, `2` is not constant there, he can test and use whatever best works for him.

Comment: @bhansa indeed i like your approach , thanks, i will use that in future.)

Answer (score 1):

In your case the page might not have loaded the form, so use [`WebDriverWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to let the element load and start scraping.

You can check for the element this way, instead of putting `time.sleep(2)` because it might take a long *time to load* it as well.

```
myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'IdOfMyElement')))
```

Also try to use the *api* if it's possible, scraping should be the second approach.

Comment: Little confusion here , did you mean `driver` instead of `browser` ? can you re-write that line for my code which i wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

The form loads after the page is loaded so here's how I did it :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://instagram.com")
time.sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("foobar")
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("pass")
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

A bit hacky at the end